# ChangeDetectionStrategy OnPush doesn't work if set it in a parent and a child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have two components.

In both components I have set `ChangeDetectionStrategy OnPush`.

AComponent (child)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
     ... ,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AComponent {

  private _value: string;

  @Input()
  set value(v: string) {
    console.log(`set value : ${v}`);
    this._value = v;
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

}
```

and AppComponent (parent).

```
@Component({
    ... ,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {

  value: string = "0";

  toClick(event) {

    // set value before request to server
    // for example to set a progress spinner    
    this.value = "1";

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('connected to server');

      //set value after request to server
      this.value = "2";
    }, 500);
  }

}
```

the template of Appcomponent (parent)

```
<app-a [value]="value" (click)="toClick()"></app-a>
```

if I click on Acomponent the `"1"` value is set, but `"2"` isn't. (you can see it on the console)

if I change `ChangeDetectionStrategy` on Default in `AppComponent` (parent),
it works correctly.

Could someone explain this behavior?

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7incmo-vp624s)**

Answer (score 3):

With `OnPush` strategy, change detection works only if an event worked on the template, in your case `toClick` and `@Input` parameters are changed. In the event handler you have an asynchronous callback function (`setTimeout`) which is already out from the event handler. So you need to manually run change detection from the callback function.

You can inject [**ChangeDetectorRef**](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and using `markForCheck` function to run change detection manually.

Check a [**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7incmo-tu6a58).